# Auto search NERDTree upon typing

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I already use CtrlP but I would like to be able to automatically move to a node in NERDTree without having to do `/foo` but instead, I want to move there (first result) when I type `foo`. This is useful when I want to see the directory structure but I'm not sure about the file name. (If I knew the file name, I'd use CtrlP)

Typing `/foo` then `Enter` is too many keystrokes for me.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: When laziness meets entitlement…

Comment: Laziness yes, but definitely not entitlement. I have switched to vim as my main editor/environment just yesterday and I'm trying to make my transition as smooth as possible. I would write my own plugins if there weren't too many things I would like to customize for now. This is why, it would be great to learn from others' experiences here, if they're willing to share. I don't believe anyone in the world is entitled to anything, including food.

Comment: The plugin's issue tracker is the right place for such questions.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this, because typing `/` isn't that much of an issue, but

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree call feedkeys('/', 't')
```

would automate it. With `:set incsearch`, you'll also see the first match highlighted. Still need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to conclude the search, though...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Ingo Karat :-) ; I'm trying to get this to work but unsuccessfully so far. I'll play around with it more and get back with you as soon as I figure out the issue but this looks promising =)